# beats per minute algorithm using only one data variable of type byte stored in an array of byte

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, beat-detection

I'm getting real time data as byte and plotting the data using timer variable on a graph using vb.net.

i want to calculate beats per minute from the graph. I've read about many peak detection algorithms but all assume to have two variables for their working.

the waveform looks like the one seen on an ECG (cardiac waveform).

I've tried the algorithm mentioned by Jean-Paul in the following post but it doesn't work for me (gives me a 0 bpm at all times)

[Peak signal detection in realtime timeseries data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-recognition-in-realtime-timeseries-data/22640362#22640362)

note: I'm storing the byte data in an array which can take atmost 2000 data points(bytes)

Comment: add sample data, how big buffer you have ?  the ECG has many peaks and you do not want peak recognition but period detection that is a bit different. you can simplify it by exploiting the graph shape like crossing specific amplitude once or twice ... etc but to propose reliable algorithm we need to see the actual data (and graphic representation is good idea to include too) for healthy and unhealthy cases you will be facing ... also you need the BPM in realtime or can be computed latter ... or what is the max dellay

Comment: @kai, add your comments as comments. Not as edit in question

Comment: @RinoTom i'm new here. thank you for pointing

Comment: @ Spektre
your comment 'exploiting the graph shape like crossing specific amplitude once or twice', i did try this by manually setting a threshold(crossing point) but the value i get remains constant for long time(the bpm value changes to new value for just a second and then returns to previous constant value). the bpm is supposed to be calculated in real time and maximum delay is 10msec. data is taken from serial port so i don't have any actual values