# How to find the peak coordinate from dataset

Tags: java, algorithm, dataset, max, data-analysis

I have a group of dataset.

This is the graph I draw using this dataset.
[image]
How to find the coordinate of peak value from this dataset?
Anyone got good java algorithm regarding this issue?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data

Answer (score 0):

For this dataset specifically, I would do the following:

1. Make the data stationary by taking first differences
2. Signal when the data is above some threshold level. You can use a fixed threshold or an adaptive threshold (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data/22640362#22640362) for example)

When I use the dataset [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583302/peak-detection-for-growing-time-series-using-swift), for illustration purposes, I get the following in Excel:

[image: Heart rate detection]

That should be easily implementable in Java.

Good luck!