# Python - finding pattern in a plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, time-series

[image]

This graph is generated by the following `gnuplot` script. The `estimated.csv` file is found in this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Iv8dfU4fTUaGRWMm9jWnBUbzg

```
# ###### GNU Plot
   set style data lines
   set terminal postscript eps enhanced color "Times" 20

   set output "cubic33_cwd_estimated.eps"

   set title "Estimated signal"

    set style line 99 linetype 1 linecolor rgb "#999999" lw 2
    #set border 1 back ls 11
    set key right top
    set key box linestyle 50
    set key width -2
    set xrange [0:10]
    set key spacing 1.2
    #set nokey

    set grid xtics ytics mytics
    #set size 2
    #set size ratio 0.4

    #show timestamp
    set xlabel "Time [Seconds]"
    set ylabel "Segments"

    set style line 1 lc rgb "#ff0000" lt 1 pi 0 pt 4 lw 4 ps 0

    # Congestion control send window

    plot  "estimated.csv" using ($1):2 with lines title "Estimated";
```

I wanted to find the pattern of the estimated signal of the previous plot something close to the following plot. My ground truth (actual signal is shown in the following plot)[image]

Here is my initial approach

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import LineString
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def load_data(fname):
    return LineString(np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter = ','))
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
lines = list(map(load_data, sys.argv[1:]))

for g in lines[0].intersection(lines[1]):
    if g.geom_type != 'Point':
        continue
    print('%f,%f' % (g.x, g.y))
```

Then invoke this python script in my `gnuplot` directly as in the following:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'fig.png'

set datafile separator comma
set yr [0:700]
set xr [0:10]

set xtics 0,2,10
set ytics 0,100,700

set grid

set xlabel "Time [seconds]"
set ylabel "Segments"

plot \
    'estimated.csv' w l lc rgb 'dark-blue' t 'Estimated', \
    'actual.csv' w l lc rgb 'green' t 'Actual', \
    '<python filter.py estimated.csv actual.csv' w p lc rgb 'red' ps 0.5 pt 7 t ''
```

which gives us the following plot. But this does not seem to give me the right pattern as gnuplot is not the best tool for such tasks.

[image]

Is there any way where we can find the pattern of the first graph (`estimated.csv`) by forming the peaks into a plot using python? If we see from the end, the pattern actually seems to be visible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a Kalman filter, it should follow the curve the way you want it.

Comment: Basically, it tries to "follow" your curve with a speed, so it will smooth your signal, but now that i think of it it won't work in your case. :/ It's great to eliminate noise and find the "True" signal, but won't help much in your case, still interresting to look in case you need it in the future. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#/media/File:Kalman.png

Comment: Some ideas through, you could use some peak detection algorithm, then use a clustering algorith like DBSCAN to eliminate oulier, and finally a Kalman Filter to smooth it all. :D

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22583761/6341054
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html
http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/KalmanFiltering.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `pandas.rolling_max()` is the right approach here. We are loading the data into a DataFrame and calculate the rolling maximum over 8500 values. Afterwards the curves look similar. You may test with the parameter a little bit to optimize the result.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
plt.ion()
names = ['actual.csv','estimated.csv']
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def load_data(fname):
    return np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter = ',')
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

data = [load_data(name) for name in names]
actual_data = data[0]
estimated_data = data[1]
df = pd.read_csv('estimated.csv', names=('x','y'))
df['rolling_max'] = pd.rolling_max(df['y'],8500)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(actual_data[:,0],actual_data[:,1], label='actual')
plt.plot(estimated_data[:,0],estimated_data[:,1], label='estimated')
plt.plot(df['x'], df['rolling_max'], label = 'rolling')

plt.legend()
plt.title('Actual vs. Interpolated')
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,500)
plt.xlabel('Time [Seconds]')
plt.ylabel('Segments')
plt.grid()
plt.show(block=True)
```

[image]

To answer the question from the comments:

Since `pd.rolling()` is generating defined windows of your data, the first values will be `NaN` for `pd.rolling().max`. To replace these `NaN`s, I suggest to turn around the whole Series and to calculate the windows backwards. Afterwards, we can replace all the `NaN`s by the values from the backwards calculation. I adjusted the window length for the backwards calculation. Otherwise we get erroneous data.

This code works:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
plt.ion()

df = pd.read_csv('estimated.csv', names=('x','y'))
df['rolling_max'] = df['y'].rolling(8500).max()
df['rolling_max_backwards'] = df['y'][::-1].rolling(850).max()
df.rolling_max.fillna(df.rolling_max_backwards, inplace=True)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df['x'], df['rolling_max'], label = 'rolling')

plt.legend()
plt.title('Actual vs. Interpolated')
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,700)
plt.xlabel('Time [Seconds]')
plt.ylabel('Segments')
plt.grid()
plt.show(block=True)
```

And we get the following result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Franz. Thank you so much. Don't use the `actual.csv` file. It is my ground truth and it should not be feed to the program. The pattern has be detected ONLY from `estimated.csv`.

Comment: Its not used for the calculation. I just used it to show the similarity. If you like to, remove the lines for the `actual.csv`

Comment: I added a solution to the code to deal with the missing values. This is not as clean as I wished it to be, but it works.

Comment: Hi Franz, have you worked with `Kalman Filters` before? I was wondering if we can try to fit this very same data with `Kalman Filter` models. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Desta, unfortunately I'm not really into Kalman Filters. Ic just read about them but didn't need them so far. Have you tried something like `pykalman`: https://pykalman.github.io ?

Comment: Hi Desta, I'm not a statistics expert. I'm sorry but I can't answer your question.