# chart.js | How to detect a summit/peak in line chart data

Tags: javascript, charts, linechart, chartjs-2.6.0

> Chart.js 2.6.0

### Expected Output

I have a problem to solve, I needed to generate this chart out of data:

[image]

### I somehow managed to generate this chart.

[image]

### Problems

- I am searching for best way to detect summit/peak of data-mountains so that I could put a point(`arc`) at the top.
- Is there a way to put labels in x-axis like in the picture above? I mean there is label after every `21` seconds.

### Code so far

Gist: https://gist.github.com/shivabhusal/efb48db79128ffd926cc25960a1d875c

I overrode the `draw` function of `Chart.js` and drew lines and points on my own.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

> **Note:** My data is not guaranteed to be pointy at the summit; sometimes it can get plateau.

---

Necessary CodePen is https://codepen.io/shivabhusal/pen/LjWyMe?editors=0010

Comment: can you please create JsFiddle, it will be more helpful

Comment: ok I will in a moment Pranav

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data

Comment: @PranavPatel I have added the link to CodePen

Comment: I've noticed that you kinda mark the areas with positive/negative slope. If you want to mark the local maximum peaks then just place the marker in the first point you're gonna paint with black (negative slope)