# Intelligent Peak Detection Method

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

I would like to detect the peaks from this data using python:

```
data = [1.0, 0.35671858559485703, 0.44709399319470694, 0.29438948200831194, 0.5163825635166547, 0.3036363865322419, 0.34031782308777747, 0.2869558046065574, 0.28190537831716, 0.2807516154537239, 0.34320479518313507, 0.21117275536958913, 0.30304626765388043, 0.4972542099530442, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.18200891715227194, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.28830608331168983, 0.057156776746163526, 0.043418555819326035, 0.022527521866967784, 0.035414574439784685, 0.062273775107322626, 0.04569227783752021, 0.04978915781132807, 0.0599089458581528, 0.05692515997545401, 0.05884619933405206, 0.0809943356922021, 0.07466587894671428, 0.08548458657792352, 0.049216679971411645, 0.04742180324984401, 0.05822208549398862, 0.03465282733964001, 0.014005094192867372, 0.052004161876744344, 0.061297263734617496, 0.01867087951563289, 0.01390993522118277, 0.021515814095838564, 0.025260618727204275, 0.0157022555745128, 0.041999490119172936, 0.0441231248537558, 0.03079711140612242, 0.04177946154195037, 0.047476050325192885, 0.05087930020034335, 0.03889899267688956, 0.02114033158686702, 0.026726959895528927, 0.04623461918879543, 0.05426474524591766, 0.04421866212189775, 0.041911901968304605, 0.019982199103543322, 0.026520396430805435, 0.03952286472888431, 0.03842652984978244, 0.02779682035551695, 0.02043518392128019, 0.07706934170969436]
```

You can plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(data)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

I encircled the peaks that I would like to automatically detect in red.

**PEAKS CHARACTERISATION:**

I am interested in finding peaks after which, for some data points (i.e. 3-4),  the signal is relatively smooth. By smooth I mean that the changes in amplitudes are comparable between the data-points after the peak. I guess, that this means in more mathematical terms: Peaks, after which for some datapoints, if you were to a fit a linear line, then the slope would be close to 0.

*What I have tried so far:*

I thought that the difference between the elements (appending 0 to have the same length) would reveal the peaks much better:

```
diff_list = []
# Append 0 to have the same length as data 
data_d = np.append(data,0)

for i in range(len(data)):
    diff = data_d[i]-data_d[i+1]

    # If difference is samller than 0, I set it to 0 -> Just interested in "falling" peaks
    if diff < 0:
        diff = 0

    diff_list= np.append(diff_list,diff)
```

When I plot `diff_list` it looks already much better:

[image]

However, a simple threshold value peak-detection algorithm does not work, because the noise in the first section has the same amplitude as the peak later on.

**So, I need a algorithm that will robustly find the peaks or a method to drastically reduce the noise without to much damping the peaks and most importantly without shifting them. Anyone has an idea ?**

**EDIT 1:**

I came across this [blog](https://blog.ytotech.com/2015/11/01/findpeaks-in-python/) and tried [this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/demotu/BMC/blob/master/notebooks/DetectPeaks.ipynb) method:

```
peaks_d = detect_peaks(diff_list, mph=None, mpd=4, threshold=0.1, edge='falling', kpsh=False, valley=False, show=False, ax=None)
plt.plot(diff_list)
plt.plot(peaks_d[:-1], diff_list[peaks_d[:-1]], "x")
plt.show()
```

...but I got:

[image]

...so really, I believe that I need some more pre-processing.

**EDIT 2:**

So I tried computing the gradient:

```
plt.plot(np.gradient(data))
```

However, the gradient within the noise is comparable to one of the peaks:
[image]

What could be used :

-> Noise: There are a multitude of similar amplitude points in a near location to each other. Maybe one could detect those areas and filter them out (i.e. set them to 0)

**EDIT 3:**

I have tried to follow [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data/43512887#43512887):

```
# Data
y = diff_list.tolist()

# Settings: lag = 30, threshold = 5, influence = 0
lag = 10
threshold = 0.1
influence = 1

# Run algo with settings from above
result = thresholding_algo(y, lag=lag, threshold=threshold, influence=influence)

# Plot result
plt.plot(result["signals"])
```

However, I get:

[image]

**EDIT 4:**

Based on a comment from @Jussi Nurminen:

> compute the absolute value of the derivative, average it for some
>   samples after the peak and see if the resulting value is "small
>   enough". Of course you have to detect all candidate peaks first. For
>   that, you could use scipy.signal.argrelextrema which detects all local
>   maxima.

```
import scipy.signal as sg
max_places = (np.array(sg.argrelmax(diff_list))[0]).tolist()
plt.plot(diff_list)
plt.plot(max_places, diff_list[max_places], "x")
plt.show()

peaks = []
for check in max_places:
    if check+5 < len(diff_list):
        gr = abs(np.average(np.gradient(diff_list[check+1: check+5])))
        if gr < 0.01:
            peaks.append(check)

plt.plot(diff_list)
plt.plot(peaks[:-1], diff_list[peaks[:-1]], "x")
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT 5:**

Here is similar data to test any algorithm:

```
data2 = [1.0, 0.4996410902399043, 0.3845950995707942, 0.38333441505960125, 0.3746384799687852, 0.28956967636700215, 0.31468441185494306, 0.5109048238958792, 0.5041481423190644, 0.41629226772762024, 0.5817609846838199, 0.3072152962171569, 0.5870564826981163, 0.4233247394608264, 0.5943712016644392, 0.4946091070102793, 0.36316740988182716, 0.4387555870158762, 0.45290920032442744, 0.48445358617984213, 0.8303387875295111, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.29678306715530073, 0.10146278147135124, 0.10120143287506084, 0.10330143251114839, 0.0802259786323741, 0.06858944745608002, 0.04600545347437729, 0.014440053029463367, 0.019023393725625705, 0.045201054387436344, 0.058496635702267374, 0.05656947149500993, 0.0463696266116956, 0.04903205756575247, 0.02781307505224703, 0.044280150764466876, 0.03746976646628557, 0.021526918040025544, 0.0038244080425488013, 0.008617907527160991, 0.0112760689575489, 0.009157686770957874, 0.013043259260489413, 0.01621417695776057, 0.016502269315028423, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.3210019708643843, 0.11441868790191953, 0.12862935834434436, 0.08790971283197381, 0.09127615787146504, 0.06360039847679771, 0.032247149009635476, 0.07225952295002563, 0.095632185243862, 0.09171396569135751, 0.07935726217072689, 0.08690487354356599, 0.08787369092132288, 0.04980466729311508, 0.05675819557118429, 0.06826614158574265, 0.08491084598657253, 0.07037944101030547, 0.06549710463329293, 0.06429902857281444, 0.07282805735716101, 0.0667027178198566, 0.05590329380937183, 0.05189048980041104, 0.04609913889901785, 0.01884014489167378, 0.02782496113905073, 0.03343588833365329, 0.028423168106849694, 0.028895130687196867, 0.03146961123393891, 0.02287127937400026, 0.012173655214339595, 0.013332601407407033, 0.014040309216796854, 0.003450677642354792, 0.010854992025496528, 0.011804042414950701, 0.008100266690771957, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.18547803170164875, 0.008457776819382444, 0.006607607749756658, 0.008566964920042127, 0.024793283595437438, 0.04334031667011553, 0.012330921737457376, 0.00994343436054472, 0.008003962298473758, 0.0025523166577987263, 0.0009309499302016907, 0.0027602202618852126, 0.0034442123857338675, 0.0006448449815386562, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

[image]

Using @jojo's answer, and choosing appropriate parameters (`dy_lim = 0.1` and `di_lim = 10`, the result is close, but there were some points added which should not be peaks.

[image]

**EDIT 5:**

Yet, another case.

```
data = [1.0, 0.0, -0.0, 0.014084507042253521, 0.0, -0.0, 0.028169014084507043, 0.0, -0.0, 0.014084507042253521, 0.0, 0.0, 0.39436619718309857, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.7887323943661971, 0.11267605633802817, 0.2535211267605634, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.4084507042253521, -0.0, 0.04225352112676056, 0.014084507042253521, 0.014084507042253521, 0.0, 0.28169014084507044, 0.04225352112676056, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.5633802816901409, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.08450704225352113, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.30985915492957744, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 0.0, 0.9295774647887324]
```

[image]

Here almost all peaks are detected correctly but one.

Comment: There's a good filter that relies on Z-scores to detect peaks, or possibly outliers. It signals when the next point exceeds a statistical threshold and is explained well with numerous software implementations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22640362/7621907

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a pragmatic solution, as the way I see this (please correct me if I'm wrong) you want to find each peak after/before a 'smooth' or 0 period.

You can do this by simply checking for such periods and reporting their start and stop.

Here is a very basic implementation, allowing to specify what qualifies as `smooth` period (I use a change of less than 0.001 as condition here):

```py
dy_lim = 0.001
targets = []
in_lock = False
i_l, d_l = 0, data[0]
for i, d in enumerate(data[1:]):
    if abs(d_l - d) > dy_lim:
        if in_lock:
            targets.append(i_l)
            targets.append(i + 1)
            in_lock = False
        i_l, d_l = i, d
    else:
        in_lock = True
```

And then plotting the `targets`:

```py
plt.plot(range(len(data)), data)
plt.scatter(targets, [data[t] for t in targets], c='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Nothing very elaborated, but it finds the peak you indicated.

Increasing the value of `dy_lim` will let you find more peaks. Also you might want to specify a minimal length of what is a smooth period, here is how this might look like (again just a crude implementation):

```py
dy_lim = 0.001
di_lim = 50
targets = []
in_lock = False
i_l, d_l = 0, data[0]
for i, d in enumerate(data[1:]):
    if abs(d_l - d) > dy_lim:
        if in_lock:
            in_lock = False
            if i - i_l > di_lim:
                targets.append(i_l)
                targets.append(i + 1)
        i_l, d_l = i, d
    else:
        in_lock = True
```

With this you would not get the first point as the difference between first and 2nd is bigger than `di_lim=50`.

---

**Update for the 2nd dataset:**

This gets a bit trickier, as now there are gradual decreases after a peak leading to a slow aggregation of difference, enough to hit the `dy_lim` leading the algorithm to falsely report a new target. So **you need to test whether this target really is a peak and only report then**.

Here is a crude implementation of how to achieve this:

```py
dy_lim = 0.1
di_lim = 5
targets = []
in_lock = False
i_l, d_l = 0, data[0]
for i, d in enumerate(data[1:]):
    if abs(d_l - d) > dy_lim:
        if in_lock:
            in_lock = False
            if i - i_l > di_lim:
                # here we check whether the start of the period was a peak
                if abs(d_l - data[i_l]) > dy_lim:
                    # assure minimal distance if previous target exists
                    if targets:
                        if i_l - targets[-1] > di_lim:
                            targets.append(i_l)
                    else:
                        targets.append(i_l)
                # and here whether the end is a peak
                if abs(d - data[i]) > dy_lim:
                    targets.append(i + 1)
        i_l, d_l = i, d
    else:
        in_lock = True
```

What you'll end up with is this:
[image]

---

*General Note*: We are following a bottom-up approach here: You have a specific feature you want to detect, so you write a specific algorithm to do so.

This can be very effective for simple tasks, however, we realize already in this simple example that if there are new features the algorithm should be able to cope with we need to adapt it. If the current complexity is all there is, then you are fine. But if the data presents yet other patterns, then you'll be again in the situation where you need to add further conditions and the algorithm becomes more and more complicated as it needs to deal with the additional complexity. If you end up in such a situation then you might want to consider switching gears and adapt a more genuine approach. There are many options in this case, one way would be to work with the difference of the original data with a [Savizky-Golay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter_for_smoothing_and_differentiation) filtered version, but that's just one of many suggestions one could make here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is a good idea, but I was actually looking for something more robust. It works for this data, but I also have other data, where there is for instance a 4th peak after a slightly rougher data stretch (i.e. non-zero)

Comment: you can handle the roughness by specifying the `dy_lim`, I'll add an example.

Comment: Okay, great ! Maybe you can try your algorithm with a similar but different dataset which I just added. (see updated question)

Comment: Can you try it again now ? It should be okay now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated answer. Maybe if one can add a minimum peak height, then such problems (as can be seen in my question) will not occur.

Comment: you could simply remove the `targets.append(i_l)` statement. You'll miss the first point, but if you look closely, the first point is also different than the others, as it has no smooth area before.

Comment: Hmm, do you have any idea how this could be fixed ?

Comment: Great answer. +1 Have a similar problem and tried to understand your code, but got a bit lost with the `in_lock` variable. Would you mind to add some more comment to explain your code ? Sorry for bothering, if you have no time, that's fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fix !!

Comment: @james Here is a short explanation of the idea behind the `on_lock`: As the algorithm runs though the dataset and we want to be able to tell whether it is currently in a smooth area or not, we set a flag, `in_lock`, that you keep on `True` as long as the difference between the current data point and the datapoint after the last 'big change' is smaller than some threshold value, `dy_lim`. If you encounter another 'big change' and you have the flag set to `True` it means you were in a 'smooth' period that you are leaving now, so you want to report this. _hope that helped, let me know if not!_

Comment: @jojo Hi ! Sorry to bother. I have come across a dataset, which I though would be easy for your code to handle. Unfortunley, it detects a small peak, where there should be none. Do you see any way of how to fix this ?

Comment: @henry hm, it will all depend on how exactly you would describe the actual peaks and, as a result, how you describe a peak that should not be found. Is there a minimal peak size? You can always adapt the minimal peak size by tuning `dy_lim`. Just from looking at your plot, maybe `dy_lim=0.15` would do?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I think that in this case, a minimal distance between peaks could be introduced. For instance, I am quite certain, that in my dataset, the peaks are more than 5 apart (x-value).

Comment: @henry indeed, this should work. I'll add a minor modification in the last version to enforce a limit on the x value (here it's the index, so I call it `di_lim`). Note that using `dy_lim=0.15` seems to work to!

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Looking forward. :) Yes, `dy_lim=0.15` works, but I have other datasets, where the peaks are much less pronounced in height. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @henry ok, it's added. now you can play around with `di_lim` to set a condition on x_values and with `dy_lim` for conditions on the peak size. :)

Comment: Very nice !! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try `scipy.signal.find_peaks` which allows you to specify different criteria (prominence, width, height etc.). However, you first have to be clear what your criteria for "peak" are. It's not sufficient to say that you want some peaks but not some other peaks - there has to be some difference between them that the algorithm can detect.

Comment: Hi ! Good answer, put please always think of providing a sample example and working on a solution with the OP's data.

Comment: Well, why is `data[13] == 0.497` a peak, but `data[4] == 0.516` is not? Until OP can answer this fundamental question in a way that can be algorithmically formulated, code examples are worthless (IMO).

Comment: Thanks for your answer/comment. To clarify: I am interested in finding peaks after which, for some data points (i.e. 3-4),  the signal is relatively smooth. By smooth I mean that the changes in amplitudes are comparable between the data-points.

Comment: @henry OK, but you have marked `data[0]` as a peak, and the signal does not look very smooth after that.

Comment: Good point. I forgot to mention, that the first datapoint is by default considered as a peak.... but it will just confuse, so I will quickly edit the image.

Comment: @henry the signal after the last peak `data[122]` does not look super smooth either. But if you want to use "smoothness after peak" as the criterion, you could just compute the absolute value of the derivative, average it for some samples after the peak and see if the resulting value is "small enough". Of course you have to detect all candidate peaks first. For that, you could use `scipy.signal.argrelextrema` which detects all local maxima.

Comment: @JussiNurminen Good idea. Will try that.