# python - How to find and visually mark the local minima of a sequence?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

How to draw a sequence of points with increasing local minima and mark them with another color? Something similar as in the picture. I am not able to set a list with that sequence and the minima are wrong. Or is there an easier way to do that?

[image: example of a plot]

I tried this code:

```
import sys
from numpy import NaN, Inf, arange, isscalar, asarray, array
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def peakdet(v, delta, x = None):
    '''
    Converted from MATLAB script at http://billauer.co.il/peakdet.html
    Returns two arrays
    function [maxtab, mintab]=peakdet(v, delta, x)
    '''
    maxtab = []
    mintab = []

    if x is None:
        x = arange(len(v))  
    v = asarray(v)
    if len(v) != len(x):
        sys.exit('Input vectors v and x must have same length')
    if not isscalar(delta):
        sys.exit('Input argument delta must be a scalar')
    if delta <= 0:
        sys.exit('Input argument delta must be positive')

    mn, mx = Inf, -Inf
    mnpos, mxpos = NaN, NaN
    lookformax = True
    for i in arange(len(v)):
        this = v[i]
        if this > mx:
            mx = this
            mxpos = x[i]
        if this < mn:
            mn = this
            mnpos = x[i]
        if lookformax:
            if this < mx-delta:
                maxtab.append((mxpos, mx))
                mn = this
                mnpos = x[i]
                lookformax = False
        else:
            if this > mn+delta:
                mintab.append((mnpos, mn))
                mx = this
                mxpos = x[i]
                lookformax = True
    return array(maxtab), array(mintab)

if __name__=="__main__":
    from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, scatter, show
    series = [7,6,5,4,3,1,3,5,6,9,12,13,10,8,6,3,5,6,7,8,13,15,11,12,9,6,4,8,9,10,15,16,17,19,22,17,15,13,11,10,7,5,8,9,12]
    maxtab, mintab = peakdet(series,.3)
    y = np.linspace(0, 10, len(series))
    plt.plot(y, series, '-', color='black');
#    scatter(array(maxtab)[:,0], array(maxtab)[:,1], color='blue')
    scatter(array(mintab)[:,0], array(mintab)[:,1], color='red')
    show()
```

I got this figure:

[image: the resulting plot]

Comment: Shouldn't you call `peakdet` with exactly the same `x` as used for plotting? How else can the line plot and the scatter have the same `x`?

Comment: Maybe you could call plt.plot with '-' instead of 'o' to get a line plot instead of just dots?  With those 2 changes the plot seems to be the way you asked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55618739/intelligent-peak-detection-method   has a vivid discussion about different approaches

Comment: @JohanC I edited the code. Is that what did you mean? The output is not what I wanted. I have a problem with plotting the scattered line.

Comment: As it is hard to explain in a comment, I posted the necessary changes to your original code as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [scipy.signal.find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html). To find minima's you multiply `series` by -1.

`find_peaks` returns the indices of peaks or minima.  To get the correct plotting positions, you have to index `x` and `series` with the output from `find_peaks`.

If you are concerned about your singal containing sequences of decreasing minima, you could compare the magnitudes of sequential peaks using `np.diff`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy as np

series = np.array([7,6,5,4,3,1,3,5,6,9,12,13,10,8,6,3,5,6,7,8,13,15,11,12,9,6,4,8,9,10,15,16,17,19,22,17,15,13,11,10,7,5,8,9,12])
peaks, _ = find_peaks(series)
mins, _ =find_peaks(series*-1)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, len(series))
plt.plot(x, series, color='black');
plt.plot(x[mins], series[mins], 'x', label='mins')
plt.plot(x[peaks], series[peaks], '*', label='peaks')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There were two mistakes in your original code:

- In your original version, you used 'o' as marker symbol in `plt.plot`. This draw dots. Now you corrected it using '-' to draw lines.
- You still didn't call your `peakdet` with the same `x` as used for plotting the line. By using a different `x` the scatter plots get placed using different x-positions as the line plot.

Please refer to @dubbbdan's answer for a good alternative for your `peakdet` function. You'll need to experiment for the best settings depending on the exact values you have in your application.

Here is your original code, but with the mistakes corrected:

```py
import sys
from numpy import NaN, Inf, arange, isscalar, array
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def peakdet(v, delta, x):
    '''
    Converted from MATLAB script at http://billauer.co.il/peakdet.html
    Returns two arrays
    function [maxtab, mintab]=peakdet(v, delta, x)
    '''
    maxtab = []
    mintab = []
    if len(v) != len(x):
        sys.exit('Input vectors v and x must have same length')
    if not isscalar(delta):
        sys.exit('Input argument delta must be a scalar')
    if delta <= 0:
        sys.exit('Input argument delta must be positive')

    mn, mx = Inf, -Inf
    mnpos, mxpos = NaN, NaN
    lookformax = True

    for i in arange(len(v)):
        this = v[i]
        if this > mx:
            mx = this
            mxpos = x[i]
        if this < mn:
            mn = this
            mnpos = x[i]

        if lookformax:
            if this < mx-delta:
                maxtab.append((mxpos, mx))
                mn = this
                mnpos = x[i]
                lookformax = False
        else:
            if this > mn+delta:
                mintab.append((mnpos, mn))
                mx = this
                mxpos = x[i]
                lookformax = True
    return array(maxtab), array(mintab)

series = [7,6,5,4,3,1,3,5,6,9,12,13,10,8,6,3,5,6,7,8,13,15,11,12,9,6,4,8,9,10,15,16,17,19,22,17,15,13,11,10,7,5,8,9,12]
x = np.linspace(0, 10, len(series))
maxtab, mintab = peakdet(series, .3, x)   # it is very important to give the correct x to `peakdet`
plt.plot(x, series, '-', color='black')   # use the same x for plotting
plt.scatter(maxtab[:,0], maxtab[:,1], color='blue') # the x-coordinates used in maxtab need to be the same as those in plot
plt.scatter(mintab[:,0], mintab[:,1], color='red')
plt.show()
```

This plots:
[image: the resulting plot]