# Trying to find a way to detect all peaks and valley points so no peaks or valley are following each other into a random signal

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, logic

I am trying to detect all pseudo half-cycles in a random signal (a half-cycle being defined simply as data between a local peak and a local valley, or the other way).

I am using the scipy `find_peaks` function.
I detect the peaks using `find_peaks(y)` and the valley with `find_peaks(-y)`, `y` being my data list (in my case, a pandas dataframe column).
I don't think that will help because my question is not fundamentally about peak detection but here are the arguments used in the `scipy.signal.find_peaks` function (pre-processing):

```
peaks_indices=find_peaks(y_data_array, distance=20, width=10, rel_height=1)[0]
valleys_indices=find_peaks(-y_data_array, distance=20, width=10, rel_height=1)[0]
```

The problem of this method is that it doesn't ensure that I will have a regular pattern of "peak, then valley, then peak, then valley, etc....."

So I wrote a function that post-processes the `peaks_indices` and `valley_indices` lists to detect following peaks or valleys. It seems to work but still misses some of them. It's been three days and I really don't understand why.

Here is the function in question:

```py
import numpy as np


def process_peaks_and_valleys(y_data_array, peaks_indices, valleys_indices):
    # Ensures the first local extremum is a peak, I'm ok to lose a few datapoints in order to normalize all my file (starts with a peak and ends with a peak)
    while valleys_indices[0] < peaks_indices[0]:
        valleys_indices = np.delete(valleys_indices, 0)
    
    # Ensure the last local extremum is a peak
    while valleys_indices[-1] > peaks_indices[-1]:
        valleys_indices = np.delete(valleys_indices, -1)
    
    print('number of peaks pre-processing = ', len(peaks_indices), '; number of valleys = ', len(valleys_indices))
    
    # Loop through the peaks and valleys to ensure an alternating pattern (peak, valley, peak, valley...)
    i = 0
    while i < len(peaks_indices):
        while i + 1 < len(peaks_indices) and peaks_indices[i + 1] < valleys_indices[i]:
            # Delete the lowest peak between peaks_indices[i] and peaks_indices[i+1]
            peaks_indices = np.delete(peaks_indices, i if y_data_array[peaks_indices[i]] < y_data_array[peaks_indices[i+1]] else i+1)
            print('following peaks detected at indices ' + str(peaks_indices[i]) + ' and ' + str(peaks_indices[i+1]), '... deleting the lowest peak')
        i += 1
    
    # Repeat the process for valleys
    i = 0
    while i < len(valleys_indices):
        while i + 1 < len(valleys_indices) and valleys_indices[i + 1] < peaks_indices[i]:
            # Delete the highest valley between valleys_indices[i] and valleys_indices[i+1]
            valleys_indices = np.delete(valleys_indices, i if y_data_array[valleys_indices[i]] > y_data_array[valleys_indices[i+1]] else i+1)
            print('following valleys detected at indices ' + str(valleys_indices[i]) + ' and ' + str(valleys_indices[i+1]), '... deleting the highest valley')
        i += 1

    # Sort the updated indices
    valleys_indices.sort()
    peaks_indices.sort()
    print('\nnumber of peaks post-processing = ', len(peaks_indices), '; number of valleys = ', len(valleys_indices))
    return peaks_indices, valleys_indices
```

I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

It seems that if I just apply the same function 3 or 4 times it ends up finding all following peaks or valley but I want it to do it on first run.

To put some context, I am working on a modelisation of the mechanical behavior of a polymer sample. This model works by updating at each cycle (half cycle for stochastic loading like here) the value of the stiffness with variables like mean tension and tension amplitude of the current half cycle. This means that I need a precise measure of tension so I don't want to smooth this experimental data you see below. The detection of the half cycles doesn't have to be very precise, I just need to detect all half cycles with an amplitude higher than 0.1 .

Here is an example of a peaks and valley detection that leaves two peaks with no valley between them (peaks in green, valleys in black). Even after running the same post process 10 times.
The code seems to not detect the following peaks:
[image: zoom on data with detected then processed peaks and valleys]

Somebody has an idea?

EDIT: I think this whole problem could be simplified to its main concept:
In two lists of numbers, I need to ensure that for each pairs of following numbers of one list, there is one and only one number from the other list that can be placed between those 2. I just don't understand why my solution doesn't do that.

P.S. I used a lot of `while` loops because I am modifying the lists length while looping through them; maybe it is a bad choice but it seems to me that it is the fastest way without having to nest `for` loops into `for` loops.

Comment: please provide example data of where the code breaks, for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: _"I am using the scipy find_peaks function"_ the code is neither using `scipy` or the `find_peaks` function...

Comment: Scipy thing is only provided context. The question is about the post-processing. Indeed representative sample of peak data is missing

Comment: You also have two valleys in a row (valleys -6 and -7, counting backwards from the right hand side). To help us fix your code we need you to supply a [mre], including enough faked data (input and desired results) to cover the edge-cases you need covering. *Plus* a description of the functional logic you're trying to implement. For example, are you trying to smooth the data, or just identify minima and maxima, does wave length matter or just amplitude, why not use a low pass filter, etc, etc. Please do read the [mre] link.

Comment: Instead of calculating your tension, etc. on every "half pseudo-cycle", which is ill-defined, why not just calculate the quantities for every input point?

Comment: The dynamic stiffness model depends on cycle variables (mean tension and amplitude) so I need to define the tension signal as a list of successives half-cycles. A half cycle being the data between a local maximum and a local minimum (or the opposite). I said pseudo because it is not a real cycle since there is no repeating pattern.

Comment: If you find some peaks or valleys are missing, also consider searching in the direction further refining parameters: you admit not understanding why things don't work for you but don't mention optimization in your post) or even other peak-picking algorithms [Peak signal detection in realtime timeseries data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22583391/12846804)

Comment: ...That being said, the scope of your post is about post-processing - please provide `peaks_indices` and `valley_indices` as input data, otherwise we cannot really help.

Comment: This answer (that applies fast Fourier transform), can probably help you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59565524/2431885

Comment: If you filter on the frequency with the _second_ highest amplitude you can quite easily find the peaks and troughs you are after