# How to Sort Values According to Sine function?

Tags: python, sorting, trigonometry, faker, heartrate

I have generated random numbers in a certain range before sorting it:

```
A = []
for _ in range(10000):
    value = np.random.randint(60,100)
    A.append(value)
A = sorted(A)
```

But what I want to do is to obtain a list of A that is sorted like the sine graph (with peaks and valleys). So essentially the values should be sorted in a manner where it gradually rises and falls with valleys at 60 and peaks at 100.

I am trying to create very simple mock data simulating heart rate. I have thought about using sort using a custom key but I don't know where to start. I've also looked into Faker but I don't think I can achieve the generated data I wanted with it (correct me if I'm wrong!)

Totally up for different solutions for this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd just generate a sine wave and use a noise library to change the wave up a bit.

Comment: Here is something that could be of some help [Robust peak detection algorithm (using z-scores)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22640362/10915018) Seems like there is a lot of information here

Comment: You can't sort a single list like this, but you can create a bunch of sub-lists and alternate between sorting them in ascending vs descending order.  I agree with the approach of starting with a sine wave and adding noise to it, though.

Comment: @tkausl Hi! thanks for replying! Sorry if this is a noobie question but by generating a sine wave, do you mean something like numpy.sin()? I've tried something similar but can't seem to get the values in the range I am looking for or in the same order as the wave.

Comment: @samwise Thank you for replying! Added a question in my reply to the user who mentioned the sine wave approach!

Comment: @FivePlyPaper thank you so much, I'll definitely give it a read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibilitie is to generate random phases, meaning the arguments for the `sin` function. You have to decide first how many cycles you want (there are one valley and one peak for each cycle). If you want `CY` cycles then you have to generate numbers in the range `(0, N * 2 * pi)`.

Then sort the phases and last apply the `sin` function to the phases.

```
import numpy as np
CY = 8
ph = np.random.rand(800) * CY * 2 * np.pi
ph.sort()
A = np.sin(ph)

# then you can plot the numbers, for example
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot(A)
plt.show()
```

[image]

the function call `np.random.rand(800)` generate 800 random numbers in the interval (0,1), so you have to multiply it to obtain the desired interval.

If you use too many numbers, the result is undistinguishable from a sin function.

Another posibilitie is start with a `sin` function and then add random numbers:

```
N = 800; CY = 8; DEV = 0.3
sin = np.sin(np.linspace(0, CY*2*np.pi, N)) 
A = sin + np.random.rand(N) * DEV
```

[image]

Also you can try changing the sin function for another