# Find a algorithm to identify a plateau

Tags: algorithm, time-series, data-science, measure, rtl-sdr

I've got the following set of data :
[image]

As you can see, I've got two plateau at 1987 and 3757. The problem is I can't find a good algorithm in order to extract them.
I've already tried this [algo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data), without any success.

Any help will be welcomed.

Regards

Comment: It is actually hard to see that there is a **plateau** there (assuming there is also not one close to 1102). Have you tried low-pass filtering your data? If it is not real-time, you can try a simple moving average. Without the data it is difficult to find the correct parameters, but it looks like something between 30 to 50 samples will help remove the noise.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It's not real time data, so I'll try to make a moving average on the data.

Comment: If it's not real-time you can simply test for structural breaks. See e.g. this question with accompanying answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395078/how-to-detect-and-quantify-a-structural-break-in-time-series-r