# Signal detection algorithm in the frequency domain

Tags: python, algorithm, signal-processing

I would like to detect signals in the frequency domain. That is, having a spectrogram, automatically determine the signal in it (its frequency and bandwidth). I tried to apply the algorithm described here [Peak signal detection in realtime timeseries data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data), but I get incorrect data (noise and incorrect signal values ​​are detected). An example of a spectrogram with which I work is in the picture. The detection of broadband signals and signals with frequency modulation is especially interesting. Perhaps someone will suggest similar implementations in python. Thank you in advance.
This is how I process the spectrum:

```
    self.L = 15  # L-point filter
    self.b = (np.ones(self.L)) / self.L  # numerator co-effs of filter transfer function
    self.a = np.ones(1)  # denominator co-effs of filter transfer function
    fft_data = np.fft.fft(balanced_signal, n=self.fft_size) / self.fft_size
    _fft_log = (np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(fft_data)))
    _fft_log = ss.lfilter(self.b, self.a, _fft_log)
    spectrum = savgol_filter(_fft_log, 100, 5,mode='nearest')
```

Then I pass this data to the signal detection function expecting to get 1 where there is a signal and 0 where there is a noise value
spectrum of mine signal:

```
    lag = 30
    threshold = 5
    influence = 0
 def thresholding_algo(self,y, lag, threshold, influence):
    signals = np.zeros(len(y))
    filteredY = np.array(y)
    avgFilter = [0] * len(y)
    stdFilter = [0] * len(y)
    avgFilter[lag - 1] = np.mean(y[0:lag])
    stdFilter[lag - 1] = np.std(y[0:lag])
    for i in range(lag, len(y)):
        if abs(y[i] - avgFilter[i - 1]) > threshold * stdFilter[i - 1]:
            if y[i] > avgFilter[i - 1]:
                signals[i] = 1
            else:
                signals[i] = -1

            filteredY[i] = influence * y[i] + (1 - influence) * filteredY[i - 1]
            avgFilter[i] = np.mean(filteredY[(i - lag + 1):i + 1])
            stdFilter[i] = np.std(filteredY[(i - lag + 1):i + 1])
        else:
            signals[i] = 0
            filteredY[i] = y[i]
            avgFilter[i] = np.mean(filteredY[(i - lag + 1):i + 1])
            stdFilter[i] = np.std(filteredY[(i - lag + 1):i + 1])

    return dict(signals=np.asarray(signals),
                avgFilter=np.asarray(avgFilter),
                stdFilter=np.asarray(stdFilter))
```

But I get detected noises. As soon as I raise the threshold to 6, I have no detection at all.
[image: spectrum]

Comment: I can also work with countdowns in the time domain.

Comment: Welcome to SO @ADRAY. Have you considered smoothing your input spectrum prior to applying your peak detection algorithm?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would use thresholding:  `if ( abs(signal - sliding_average(signal)) >= threshold )  this_is_peak` ... also the spectrum is power spectrum?  You know FFT produce complex domain results so you have to convert to real domain firstor use different frequency domain conversion like band pass filters DCT or DST.

Comment: @itprorh66 I apologize for the incorrectness of the question. I have edited it, but I hope to clarify my intentions.

Comment: @Sheldon I think the answer to your questions is in the edited description above.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For noisy signal like this is best to use sliding average and threshold that or diference between it and original signal. Which method to use depends on what you want to achieve and what you consider to be useful signal so either:

```
if ( abs(signal - sliding_average(signal)) >= positive_threshold )  this_is_signal;
```

or

```
if ( sliding_average(signal) <= negative_threshold )  this_is_signal;
```

Note that your values are negative that is why I used negative threshold and `<=` in the second example.

Also I hope the spectrum is power spectrum (You know FFT produce complex domain results so you have to convert to real domain first or use different frequency domain conversion like band pass filters DCT or DST in order to use real domain approaches)

In your case (signal with "horizontal base line") I would use the second option... Not a python coder but I tried it in C++/VCL with sliding average window size of 11 samples and threshold `-117.0` the result:

[image: preview]

In **yellow** is your "original" input (extracted from image) , the sliding average is in **aqua** the threshold value is in **dark green** and threshold result is in **green**.

Here C++/VCL code I did this with:

```cpp
//$$---- Form CPP ----
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "win_main.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int xs,ys;
Graphics::TBitmap *bmp;
float *data_in=NULL,*data_out=NULL;
int n;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
float* load_graph(int &size,float y0,float y1,AnsiString filename)
    {
    int x,y,xs,ys;
    DWORD **pyx,c;
    float a,my,*data=NULL;
    Graphics::TBitmap *bmp;
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->LoadFromFile(filename);
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;
    xs=bmp->Width;
    ys=bmp->Height;
    size=xs;

    data=new float[size];
    pyx=new DWORD*[ys];
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++) pyx[y]=(DWORD*)bmp->ScanLine[y];
    my=(y1-y0)/float(ys-1);

    for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
     for (data[x]=y0,y=0;y<ys;y++)
      if ((pyx[y][x]&0x00FFFFFF)==0x00FFFF00)
        {
        a=y0+(float(ys-1-y)*my);
        data[x]=a;
        break;
        }

    delete[] pyx;
    delete bmp;
    return data;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void draw()
    {
    int i;
    float x,y,dx,y0,y1,dy;
    bmp->Canvas->Brush->Color=clBlack;
    bmp->Canvas->FillRect(TRect(0,0,xs,ys));

    y0=-123.0;
    y1= -70.0;
    dx=float(xs)/float(n);
    dy=float(ys)/float(y1-y0);

    // render input data
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=TColor(0x00008080); // yellow
    for (x=0.0,i=0;i<n;i++,x+=dx)
        {
        y=(y1-data_in[i])*dy;
        if (!i) bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
        else    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y);
        }

    // render output data
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=TColor(0x00F0F000); // aqua
    for (x=0.0,i=0;i<n;i++,x+=dx)
        {
        y=(y1-data_out[i])*dy;
        if (!i) bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
        else    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y);
        }

    // render threshold
    float thr=-117.0;
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=TColor(0x00008000); // dark green
    y=(y1-thr)*dy;
    bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(0,y);
    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(xs-1,y);
    bmp->Canvas->Pen->Color=TColor(0x0000F000); // green
    for (x=0.0,i=0;i<n;i++,x+=dx)
        {
        y=ys>>3;
//      if (fabs(data_in[i]-data_out[i])>=5.0) y-=ys>>4;
        if (fabs(data_out[i])<=-thr) y-=ys>>4;
        if (!i) bmp->Canvas->MoveTo(x,y);
        else    bmp->Canvas->LineTo(x,y);
        }

    Form1->Canvas->Draw(0,0,bmp);
    bmp->SaveToFile("out.bmp");
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    bmp=new Graphics::TBitmap;
    bmp->HandleType=bmDIB;
    bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit;

    data_in=load_graph(n,-123.2,-70.0,"noise.bmp");
    data_out=new float[n];

    int i,j,k,m=5; // sliding average
    float a;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        for (a=0.0,j=i-m;j<=i+m;j++)
            {
            k=j;
            if (k< 0) k=0;
            if (k>=n) k=n-1;
            a+=data_in[k];
            }
        data_out[i]=a/float(m+m+1);
        }

    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    delete[] data_in;
    delete[] data_out;
    delete bmp;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    xs=ClientWidth;
    ys=ClientHeight;
    bmp->Width=xs;
    bmp->Height=ys;
    draw();
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And input Image I used for data extraction:

[image: input noise]

Most of the code is not important just look at the stuff marked with these comments:

```
// render threshold
// sliding average
```

the `data_in[]` is your input data, `data_out[]` is sliding average (with `m` as its half strength) and `thr` is the threshold.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for my purposes. But now I would like to determine the bandwidth of the signal. I have a question, how should I divide the frequencies among themselves?

Comment: That is, a situation arises when there are 1 or several zeros in the detection, but it is still one frequency. At the output, I would like to have, for example, a frequency = 910 MHz, a band of 500 kHz.

Comment: @ADRAY if by bandwith you mean the width of detected signal in frequency domain you just find first thresholded frequency `f0` and last `f1` then bandwith is `f1-f0` in case you do not want to incorporate gaps then you just sum up the thresholded fequencies. If I get your last comment right you want to have minimal width of threshoded signal of 500 KHz so you can add aditional filter to detect smaller leaks in treshold and enlarge them if needed.