# How can I get the beats per minute using FFT on the amplitude data?

Tags: javascript, fft

I checked all the answers on stackoverflow regarding this topic, but any solution does not work with my dataset.
The dataset consists of 600 amplitudes sampled at 60 samples per second.
In this dataset, there are 13 beats in 10 seconds.
So the result should be around 78 beats per minute.
I know I could use peak detection in various ways, but I wish to know if there is a way to detect it using FFT (fftjs).
I also tried this great approach [Peak signal detection in realtime timeseries data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data/22640362)
but it doesn't seem to work well with this dataset.

```js
$(function() {

  function out(array) {
    $("#console").html($("#console").html() + "<br/><br/>" + JSON.stringify(array));
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
  }
  var fft = new FFT({samplingRate:60});

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////                INPUT DATA
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // If you test sine curve, please change flag WAVEFORM_TEST to true.
  
  var WAVEFORM_TEST = false;
  
  var real = [];
  if (WAVEFORM_TEST) {
    N = 320;
    k = 40;
    // frequency = (k/N)
    for (i = 0; i<N; i++){
      real.push(Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * k * i) / N ));
    }
  } else {
      real = [.5,.5,-.7000000000000001,-.9,-.9,-.1,.10000000000000003,.10000000000000003,-.8000000000000002,-.8000000000000002,.8999999999999999,-4,-6.3,-3.5,1.7999999999999996,5.199999999999999,5.199999999999999,5.7,2,2,.6,-.10000000000000003,-1.1,-2.8,-1.2999999999999998,1.0000000000000002,1.0000000000000002,-2.3000000000000003,-4.5,-4.5,-.20000000000000007,1.0000000000000004,1.0000000000000004,.8000000000000003,-.6,-.6,-.3000000000000001,.4000000000000001,.6000000000000002,.10000000000000009,-.6,-.6,-.8999999999999999,-.20000000000000004,-.20000000000000004,1.1,1.4,1.0999999999999999,.6,.10000000000000006,-.6000000000000001,-.8,.19999999999999993,.19999999999999993,-1.9000000000000001,-1.5999999999999999,-1.5999999999999999,1.6,-3.3,-6.3,-3.6,2.1000000000000005,5.999999999999999,5.999999999999999,4,4,1.2000000000000002,-.6000000000000001,-.6000000000000001,-.9,-.9000000000000001,-.9000000000000001,2.5000000000000004,2.9000000000000004,-1.1000000000000003,-1.1000000000000003,-4.3,-1.8,-1.8,.09999999999999998,.09999999999999998,0,.9000000000000001,1.9000000000000004,2.4,2.3,1.5999999999999996,1.5999999999999996,.30000000000000004,-.20000000000000007,-.20000000000000007,-.4,-.4,.30000000000000004,2.6,2.4000000000000004,.9999999999999999,-.8,-1.6,-1.6,-.5000000000000001,-1.2999999999999998,-1.2999999999999998,2.4000000000000004,2.1999999999999997,2.1999999999999997,-8.100000000000001,-6.4,-.6,-.6,6,6,4.4,-.49999999999999994,-.49999999999999994,-.7999999999999998,-1,-1,-1.2,1.4000000000000004,3.4,3.4,-3.6,-4.199999999999999,-4.199999999999999,.7999999999999999,.7999999999999999,1.9,.9000000000000001,.9000000000000001,.30000000000000004,0,0,0,-.10000000000000003,-.7000000000000001,-.7000000000000001,.20000000000000004,.9,.9,1.9000000000000001,1.9000000000000001,1.9,.9000000000000001,0,0,-1.6,-.7000000000000001,-.7000000000000001,-1.5,1.5,1.5,3.3,1.3877787807814457e-16,-6.7,-2.1,3.4,3.4,6.300000000000001,2.7,2.7,.19999999999999987,.30000000000000004,.30000000000000004,.5,-.6000000000000001,1.1,3,.6000000000000001,-4.7,-4.7,-6.4,0,0,.9000000000000002,.9000000000000002,.4999999999999999,1.4000000000000001,1.3,1.3,-.1,-.1,-.6000000000000001,-.8,-.30000000000000004,-.30000000000000004,.7000000000000002,.8000000000000002,.8000000000000002,1.6,1.0999999999999999,.5,-.1,-.1,-.8,-.5000000000000001,-1.1,-1.1,-1.2000000000000002,4.400000000000001,4.400000000000001,.5,-5.999999999999999,-2.9000000000000004,3.0999999999999996,6.300000000000001,6.300000000000001,6.300000000000001,2.6999999999999997,2.6999999999999997,1.5,-.8000000000000002,-.8000000000000002,-1.9,.09999999999999998,1.6,1.6,-4.3999999999999995,-5.300000000000001,-5.300000000000001,.3999999999999999,1.9999999999999998,1.9999999999999998,2.2,2,2,.5,-.2,-.2,-.3000000000000001,-.5,-.5,-.6,-.20000000000000004,-.20000000000000004,1.4,1.4,1.5000000000000002,.9000000000000001,.8,.8,-.7000000000000001,-1.4000000000000004,-1.4000000000000004,-.9999999999999999,-1.3,-.3,-.3,2.7,2.7,-7.700000000000001,-6,-.2999999999999998,-.2999999999999998,7.200000000000001,6.300000000000001,6.300000000000001,2,2,.19999999999999996,-2.2,-2.2,-.5,2.1,2.4,2.4,-4.9,-3.8000000000000007,-1.3,.29999999999999993,.30000000000000004,.30000000000000004,.5,.5,.8,-.4000000000000001,-.4000000000000001,-1.4999999999999998,-1.5000000000000002,-1.5000000000000002,-1.6,-1.3000000000000003,-1.3000000000000003,-.1,1.5999999999999999,1.4,.9,1.2999999999999998,1.8,1.6,1.6,-1,-1,-1.5999999999999999,-2.7755575615628914e-17,-2.7755575615628914e-17,-.9000000000000001,1.5,2.5,2.5,-6.699999999999999,-5.4,-5.4,5.2,6.7,6.7,2.6,.8999999999999999,.8999999999999999,.1,-.9999999999999999,-1.7,-1,1.4,2,-1.5,-4.3,-4.3,-.6000000000000001,.8999999999999999,.8999999999999999,.8,.8,.4,.2,.10000000000000003,.10000000000000003,-.4,-.7999999999999999,-.7999999999999999,-1.2000000000000002,-.30000000000000004,-.30000000000000004,1.2,1.1,1.1,.6,.3,.3999999999999999,.3999999999999999,-.20000000000000004,-.20000000000000004,-1.1,-.30000000000000004,-.30000000000000004,-.4,-.3000000000000001,2.6999999999999997,1.7000000000000002,-3.7999999999999994,-6.8,-6.8,2.1000000000000005,2.1000000000000005,5.8,4.3,4.3,2.1,.20000000000000004,-.9,-1.7000000000000002,-2.0000000000000004,-.4,-.4,1.1,1.1,-2.6999999999999997,-2.7,-.29999999999999993,-.29999999999999993,1.2999999999999998,1.2999999999999998,.8,.09999999999999998,.2,.2,-.1,-.30000000000000004,-.30000000000000004,-.9,-.9,-.9,-.2,.7000000000000001,1,1,1,1.4,1.4,.2,.2,-1.1,-1.4000000000000001,-1.4000000000000001,0,-.5000000000000001,-.5000000000000001,0,1.9,-3.5000000000000004,-3.5000000000000004,-5.199999999999999,-5.199999999999999,.40000000000000024,5.8,5.8,4.7,1.1,.1,.1,-1.5000000000000002,-1.7000000000000004,-1.7000000000000004,2,1.7,1.7,-4.6000000000000005,-4.6000000000000005,-3.6,.40000000000000013,.40000000000000013,1.4000000000000001,1.3,.8,.8,.30000000000000004,-.10000000000000003,-.10000000000000003,-.8,-1.1,-1.1,-1.1,.8000000000000002,1.3000000000000003,1.3000000000000003,.4,.2,.2,1.0000000000000002,1.0000000000000002,.4,-1.4000000000000001,-.4,-.4,-.7,-1.3000000000000003,-1.3000000000000003,2.4,-1.5,-1.5,-6.300000000000001,-1.5,-1.5,6.2,6.2,3.1000000000000005,1.2,.8000000000000002,.8000000000000002,-.29999999999999993,-.7999999999999999,-.7999999999999999,1,2,2,-5,-5,-3.5,-.6000000000000001,1.4,1.8,1.8,.7999999999999999,-8.326672684688674e-17,-8.326672684688674e-17,-.30000000000000004,-.30000000000000004,-.6,-.8999999999999999,-1.0000000000000002,-1.1000000000000003,-.8,-.8,-.2,1.5999999999999999,2.4000000000000004,2.4000000000000004,1.1,1.1,-.4,-1.7,-1.7,0,-.8,-1,-1,3,-1.0999999999999999,-1.0999999999999999,-6.6000000000000005,-1.5,-1.5,6,5.500000000000001,5.500000000000001,1.9,.20000000000000007,.20000000000000007,-.7,-1,-1,.7000000000000001,2.3,2.3,-4.6000000000000005,-5,-2.4,-2.4,1.2999999999999998,1.2000000000000002,1.2000000000000002,.7,.7,.8,.10000000000000009,.10000000000000009,-.8,-1.4000000000000001,-1.4000000000000001,-1.4000000000000001,0,1.4,1.4,2.1,1.3,.4,-.5,-.5,-1.3,-1,-1.5000000000000002,-1.5999999999999999,.8000000000000002,3.8,3.8,-4.6,-7.3,-7.3,1.7999999999999998,1.7999999999999998,6.1000000000000005,4.3,2.3,.9000000000000001,0,-.8,-.8,-1.3,-.1,-.1,1.4000000000000001,-3,-5.2,-5.2,-.7999999999999999,.8999999999999998,.8999999999999998,1.1,.5,.5,.3,.3,.2,-.1,-.1,-.5999999999999999,-.7,-.4,-.4,.9000000000000001,.9000000000000001,1.5999999999999999,1.3000000000000003,1.3000000000000003,.1,-1.4000000000000001,-1,-1.4000000000000001,-2,.4000000000000001,3,.8999999999999999,-4.8,-4.8,-3.6000000000000005,2.5999999999999996,2.5999999999999996,6.3,4.1,1.6];



  }
  
  var imaginary = new Array(real.length);
  imaginary.fill(0);

  original = real.slice(0);
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////                 OUTPUT
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

  out('Original source (real array)');
  out(original);

  fft.calc(60, real, imaginary);
  out('FFT');
  out(real);
  out(imaginary);

  var amplitude = fft.amplitude(real, imaginary);
  out("amplitude");
  out(amplitude);

  var power = fft.power(real, imaginary);
  out("power");
  out(power);

  var phase = fft.phase(real, imaginary);
  out("phase");
  out(phase);

  var frequencies = fft.frequencies(real, imaginary, 60);
  out("frequencies");
  out(frequencies);

  var periods = fft.periods(real, imaginary, 60);
  out("periods");
  out(periods);

  var data1 = [{
    name: 'original source',
    y: original
  }];

  var data2 = [{
    name: 'real array',
    y: real
  }, {
    name: 'imaginary array',
    y: imaginary
  }];

  var data3 = [{
    name: 'amplitude array',
    x: frequencies,
    y: amplitude
  }, {
    name: 'phase array',
    x: frequencies,
    y: phase
  }];

  Plotly.plot('stage1', data1, {
    title: 'original source',
    xaxis: {
      title: 'index'
    }
  });
  Plotly.plot('stage2', data2, {
    title: 'FFT',
    xaxis: {
      title: 'index'
    }
  });
  Plotly.plot('stage3', data3, {
    title: 'amplitude, phase vs frequency',
    xaxis: {
      title: 'frequencies'
    }
  });

  out('iFFT');
  fft.calc(-1, real, imaginary);
  out(real);
  out(imaginary);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hotstaff/jquery.fft/master/jquery.fft.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <H2>Example</H2>
  <div id="stage1"></div>
  <div id="stage2"></div>
  <div id="stage3"></div>
  <div id="console"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm somewhat of a "hack" at signal processing, but I don't think you have enough samples to support the FFT being implemented.  "the math" says you should be able to detect this frequency with your sampling rate.  It appears that the FFT you used is 1024 sample FFT, but you only have 600 datapoints which isn't going to work well.  Can you control the size of the FFT?  ...512 should work, but with a little less resolution, which should be OK. Or gather a bigger sample?

Comment: @AirSquid where do you see the FFT size in my example?

Comment: By using the code execution feature (which is kinda neat).  The displayed FFT output has 1024 bins, likely the default.

Comment: yep, but I tried with other FFT and smaller FFT size, and I get the same result. Probably this FFT fills the missing data with 0... so the result is the same. I ended up writing my own algorithm to get the BPM..

Comment: @AirSquid I found the way... :D

Comment: Found a way to change the size of the FFT and got reasonable results or did something else?  I would have thought that zero-fill should also work, but as stated:  I'm a hack here!  :)

Comment: @AirSquid https://stackoverflow.com/a/74954365/236062

Answer (score 0):

I **knew** there was a way!
In the third graph, you will see that the highest peak is the average BPM of the sample.

In other words: thinking about the whole sample as a complex wave, with an FFT we get a "dissection" of the frequencies of the sample.
So the strongest one is the main wave you can see with your eyes in the sample data. And it's exactly the average BPM of the sample.

```js
$(function() {

  function out(array) {
    $("#console").html($("#console").html() + "<br/><br/>" + JSON.stringify(array));
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
  }
  var fft = new FFT(512);

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////                INPUT DATA
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // If you test sine curve, please change flag WAVEFORM_TEST to true.

  var WAVEFORM_TEST = false;

  var real = [];
  if (WAVEFORM_TEST) {
    N = 320;
    k = 40;
    // frequency = (k/N)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      real.push(Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * k * i) / N));
    }
  } else {
    real = [.5, .5, -.7000000000000001, -.9, -.9, -.1, .10000000000000003, .10000000000000003, -.8000000000000002, -.8000000000000002, .8999999999999999, -4, -6.3, -3.5, 1.7999999999999996, 5.199999999999999, 5.199999999999999, 5.7, 2, 2, .6, -.10000000000000003, -1.1, -2.8, -1.2999999999999998, 1.0000000000000002, 1.0000000000000002, -2.3000000000000003, -4.5, -4.5, -.20000000000000007, 1.0000000000000004, 1.0000000000000004, .8000000000000003, -.6, -.6, -.3000000000000001, .4000000000000001, .6000000000000002, .10000000000000009, -.6, -.6, -.8999999999999999, -.20000000000000004, -.20000000000000004, 1.1, 1.4, 1.0999999999999999, .6, .10000000000000006, -.6000000000000001, -.8, .19999999999999993, .19999999999999993, -1.9000000000000001, -1.5999999999999999, -1.5999999999999999, 1.6, -3.3, -6.3, -3.6, 2.1000000000000005, 5.999999999999999, 5.999999999999999, 4, 4, 1.2000000000000002, -.6000000000000001, -.6000000000000001, -.9, -.9000000000000001, -.9000000000000001, 2.5000000000000004, 2.9000000000000004, -1.1000000000000003, -1.1000000000000003, -4.3, -1.8, -1.8, .09999999999999998, .09999999999999998, 0, .9000000000000001, 1.9000000000000004, 2.4, 2.3, 1.5999999999999996, 1.5999999999999996, .30000000000000004, -.20000000000000007, -.20000000000000007, -.4, -.4, .30000000000000004, 2.6, 2.4000000000000004, .9999999999999999, -.8, -1.6, -1.6, -.5000000000000001, -1.2999999999999998, -1.2999999999999998, 2.4000000000000004, 2.1999999999999997, 2.1999999999999997, -8.100000000000001, -6.4, -.6, -.6, 6, 6, 4.4, -.49999999999999994, -.49999999999999994, -.7999999999999998, -1, -1, -1.2, 1.4000000000000004, 3.4, 3.4, -3.6, -4.199999999999999, -4.199999999999999, .7999999999999999, .7999999999999999, 1.9, .9000000000000001, .9000000000000001, .30000000000000004, 0, 0, 0, -.10000000000000003, -.7000000000000001, -.7000000000000001, .20000000000000004, .9, .9, 1.9000000000000001, 1.9000000000000001, 1.9, .9000000000000001, 0, 0, -1.6, -.7000000000000001, -.7000000000000001, -1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 3.3, 1.3877787807814457e-16, -6.7, -2.1, 3.4, 3.4, 6.300000000000001, 2.7, 2.7, .19999999999999987, .30000000000000004, .30000000000000004, .5, -.6000000000000001, 1.1, 3, .6000000000000001, -4.7, -4.7, -6.4, 0, 0, .9000000000000002, .9000000000000002, .4999999999999999, 1.4000000000000001, 1.3, 1.3, -.1, -.1, -.6000000000000001, -.8, -.30000000000000004, -.30000000000000004, .7000000000000002, .8000000000000002, .8000000000000002, 1.6, 1.0999999999999999, .5, -.1, -.1, -.8, -.5000000000000001, -1.1, -1.1, -1.2000000000000002, 4.400000000000001, 4.400000000000001, .5, -5.999999999999999, -2.9000000000000004, 3.0999999999999996, 6.300000000000001, 6.300000000000001, 6.300000000000001, 2.6999999999999997, 2.6999999999999997, 1.5, -.8000000000000002, -.8000000000000002, -1.9, .09999999999999998, 1.6, 1.6, -4.3999999999999995, -5.300000000000001, -5.300000000000001, .3999999999999999, 1.9999999999999998, 1.9999999999999998, 2.2, 2, 2, .5, -.2, -.2, -.3000000000000001, -.5, -.5, -.6, -.20000000000000004, -.20000000000000004, 1.4, 1.4, 1.5000000000000002, .9000000000000001, .8, .8, -.7000000000000001, -1.4000000000000004, -1.4000000000000004, -.9999999999999999, -1.3, -.3, -.3, 2.7, 2.7, -7.700000000000001, -6, -.2999999999999998, -.2999999999999998, 7.200000000000001, 6.300000000000001, 6.300000000000001, 2, 2, .19999999999999996, -2.2, -2.2, -.5, 2.1, 2.4, 2.4, -4.9, -3.8000000000000007, -1.3, .29999999999999993, .30000000000000004, .30000000000000004, .5, .5, .8, -.4000000000000001, -.4000000000000001, -1.4999999999999998, -1.5000000000000002, -1.5000000000000002, -1.6, -1.3000000000000003, -1.3000000000000003, -.1, 1.5999999999999999, 1.4, .9, 1.2999999999999998, 1.8, 1.6, 1.6, -1, -1, -1.5999999999999999, -2.7755575615628914e-17, -2.7755575615628914e-17, -.9000000000000001, 1.5, 2.5, 2.5, -6.699999999999999, -5.4, -5.4, 5.2, 6.7, 6.7, 2.6, .8999999999999999, .8999999999999999, .1, -.9999999999999999, -1.7, -1, 1.4, 2, -1.5, -4.3, -4.3, -.6000000000000001, .8999999999999999, .8999999999999999, .8, .8, .4, .2, .10000000000000003, .10000000000000003, -.4, -.7999999999999999, -.7999999999999999, -1.2000000000000002, -.30000000000000004, -.30000000000000004, 1.2, 1.1, 1.1, .6, .3, .3999999999999999, .3999999999999999, -.20000000000000004, -.20000000000000004, -1.1, -.30000000000000004, -.30000000000000004, -.4, -.3000000000000001, 2.6999999999999997, 1.7000000000000002, -3.7999999999999994, -6.8, -6.8, 2.1000000000000005, 2.1000000000000005, 5.8, 4.3, 4.3, 2.1, .20000000000000004, -.9, -1.7000000000000002, -2.0000000000000004, -.4, -.4, 1.1, 1.1, -2.6999999999999997, -2.7, -.29999999999999993, -.29999999999999993, 1.2999999999999998, 1.2999999999999998, .8, .09999999999999998, .2, .2, -.1, -.30000000000000004, -.30000000000000004, -.9, -.9, -.9, -.2, .7000000000000001, 1, 1, 1, 1.4, 1.4, .2, .2, -1.1, -1.4000000000000001, -1.4000000000000001, 0, -.5000000000000001, -.5000000000000001, 0, 1.9, -3.5000000000000004, -3.5000000000000004, -5.199999999999999, -5.199999999999999, .40000000000000024, 5.8, 5.8, 4.7, 1.1, .1, .1, -1.5000000000000002, -1.7000000000000004, -1.7000000000000004, 2, 1.7, 1.7, -4.6000000000000005, -4.6000000000000005, -3.6, .40000000000000013, .40000000000000013, 1.4000000000000001, 1.3, .8, .8, .30000000000000004, -.10000000000000003, -.10000000000000003, -.8, -1.1, -1.1, -1.1, .8000000000000002, 1.3000000000000003, 1.3000000000000003, .4, .2, .2, 1.0000000000000002, 1.0000000000000002, .4, -1.4000000000000001, -.4, -.4, -.7, -1.3000000000000003, -1.3000000000000003, 2.4, -1.5, -1.5, -6.300000000000001, -1.5, -1.5, 6.2, 6.2, 3.1000000000000005, 1.2, .8000000000000002, .8000000000000002, -.29999999999999993, -.7999999999999999, -.7999999999999999, 1, 2, 2, -5, -5, -3.5, -.6000000000000001, 1.4, 1.8, 1.8, .7999999999999999, -8.326672684688674e-17, -8.326672684688674e-17, -.30000000000000004, -.30000000000000004, -.6, -.8999999999999999, -1.0000000000000002, -1.1000000000000003, -.8, -.8, -.2, 1.5999999999999999, 2.4000000000000004, 2.4000000000000004, 1.1, 1.1, -.4, -1.7, -1.7, 0, -.8, -1, -1, 3, -1.0999999999999999, -1.0999999999999999, -6.6000000000000005, -1.5, -1.5, 6, 5.500000000000001, 5.500000000000001, 1.9, .20000000000000007, .20000000000000007, -.7, -1, -1, .7000000000000001, 2.3, 2.3, -4.6000000000000005, -5, -2.4, -2.4, 1.2999999999999998, 1.2000000000000002, 1.2000000000000002, .7, .7, .8, .10000000000000009, .10000000000000009, -.8, -1.4000000000000001, -1.4000000000000001, -1.4000000000000001, 0, 1.4, 1.4, 2.1, 1.3, .4, -.5, -.5, -1.3, -1, -1.5000000000000002, -1.5999999999999999, .8000000000000002, 3.8, 3.8, -4.6, -7.3, -7.3, 1.7999999999999998, 1.7999999999999998, 6.1000000000000005, 4.3, 2.3, .9000000000000001, 0, -.8, -.8, -1.3, -.1, -.1, 1.4000000000000001, -3, -5.2, -5.2, -.7999999999999999, .8999999999999998, .8999999999999998, 1.1, .5, .5, .3, .3, .2, -.1, -.1, -.5999999999999999, -.7, -.4, -.4, .9000000000000001, .9000000000000001, 1.5999999999999999, 1.3000000000000003, 1.3000000000000003, .1, -1.4000000000000001, -1, -1.4000000000000001, -2, .4000000000000001, 3, .8999999999999999, -4.8, -4.8, -3.6000000000000005, 2.5999999999999996, 2.5999999999999996, 6.3, 4.1, 1.6];



  }

  var imaginary = new Array(real.length);
  imaginary.fill(0);

  original = real.slice(real.length - 512);
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  ////                 OUTPUT
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////

  out('Original source (real array)');
  out(original);

  fft = new FFT(original.length, 60);
  fft.forward(original);

  out('FFT');
  out(fft.spectrum);


  time = Array(512).fill(0).map((a, b) => b / 60);

  var data1 = [{
    name: 'original source',
    y: original,
    x: time
  }];

  sn = Array(256).fill(0).map((a, b) => b);
  fftdata = Array.from(fft.spectrum);

  var data2 = [{
    name: 'fft data',
    y: fftdata,
    x: sn //freqs
  }];

  sn3 = Array(256).fill(0).map((a, b) => 60 * b * 30 / 256);

  var data3 = [{
    name: 'BPM',
    y: fftdata.slice(5, 20),
    x: sn3.slice(5, 20)
  }];

  font = {
    family: "Times New Roman",
    size: 18
  };

  Plotly.newPlot('stage1', data1, {
    title: 'Sensor data',
    xaxis: {
      title: 'seconds'
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: 'signal'
    },
    font: font
  });

  Plotly.newPlot('stage2', data2, {
    title: 'FFT data',
    xaxis: {
      title: 'bin #'
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: 'signal'
    },
    font: font
  });

  Plotly.newPlot('stage3', data3, {
    title: 'BPM',
    xaxis: {
      title: 'BPM'
    },
    yaxis: {
      title: 'Amplitude'
    },
    font: font
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://dyns.gq/test/zfft.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/plotly.js@2.16.5/dist/plotly.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <H2>Example</H2>
  <div id="stage1"></div>
  <div id="stage2"></div>
  <div id="stage3"></div>
  <div id="console"></div>
</body>
```