# How do I split up a giant single column of time series data (repeat pulses) into discrete columns in Python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm working with a company that's implemented a single data logger recording the results of their instrument over time. It can scan for hours, or days, sending out a pulse every so often and then recording a fluctuation in signal. Then repeats. The output is a single csv file with two columns: elapsed time and response.

Any ideas wise ones?

[image: Screenshot of data type for 4 pulses]

I've easily brought the data into Jupyter Notebook and thought about using something to confirm the data must rise for 10 rows in a row (i.e. monotonic increase) but that doesn't work because some times there are 10 rows that increase a tiny amount...

Comment: What is your specific question?  This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code.  As written, your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [what are you asking].

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of the data? Is the sampling rate (time difference between two data points) constant?

Comment: Seems like what you should be looking for is peak detection algorithm. They exist. Probably not something SO is going to do for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Peak signal detection in realtime timeseries data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22583391/peak-signal-detection-in-realtime-timeseries-data)